# Display Conditional Content in Wordpress Template

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

Alright, so I have this block of code in my current theme:

```
<div class="content_block">

                <?php the_content(); ?>

                <div class="<?php echo $left_block; ?>">

                    <?php  $project_photos = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'project_photo_photo' );
                        if ( $project_photos ) : ?>
                                <div class="grid_gallery clearfix">
                                    <?php foreach( $project_photos as $project_photo ) { ?>
                                        <figure class="gallery_item featured-thumbnail thumbnail single-gallery-item">
                                            <a href="/brv2/wp-content/files_mf/<?php echo $project_photo; ?>" class="image-wrap" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]">
                                                <img class="project_photo_photo" width="260" src="/brv2/wp-content/files_mf/<?php echo $project_photo; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                                            <span class="zoom-icon"></span>
                                            </a>
                                        </figure>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    <!--END .slider -->
                                </div>           
                        <?php endif; ?>
```

What I need to do is to add a DIV wrap around "the_content" if and only if the $project_photos selector is active, not being a PHP developer this is what I've come up with but it doesn't work:

```
<div class="content_block">

                <?php if ( $project_photos() ) {

                        echo '<div class="project_description">';
                        the_content(); 
                        echo '</div>';

                    } else {

                        the_content(); 

                    } ?>

                <div class="<?php echo $left_block; ?>">

                    <?php  $project_photos = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'project_photo_photo' );
                        if ( $project_photos ) : ?>
                                <div class="grid_gallery clearfix">
                                    <?php foreach( $project_photos as $project_photo ) { ?>
                                        <figure class="gallery_item featured-thumbnail thumbnail single-gallery-item">
                                            <a href="/brv2/wp-content/files_mf/<?php echo $project_photo; ?>" class="image-wrap" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]">
                                                <img class="project_photo_photo" width="260" src="/brv2/wp-content/files_mf/<?php echo $project_photo; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                                            <span class="zoom-icon"></span>
                                            </a>
                                        </figure>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    <!--END .slider -->
                                </div>           
                        <?php endif; ?>
```

If anyone could provide some guidance on how I might accomplish this I would be very grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it default post or custom post type?

Comment: It's a custom post type

Comment: for that you can create a custom php page http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates Try to read this ..might me helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you give this a try?

```
 <div class="content_block">

                <?php 
                        $project_photos = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'project_photo_photo' );

                        if ( $project_photos ) {

                        echo '<div class="project_description">';
                        the_content(); 
                        echo '</div>';

                    } else {

                        the_content(); 

                    } ?>

                <div class="<?php echo $left_block; ?>">

                    <?php
                        if ( $project_photos ) : ?>
                                <div class="grid_gallery clearfix">
                                    <?php foreach( $project_photos as $project_photo ) { ?>
                                        <figure class="gallery_item featured-thumbnail thumbnail single-gallery-item">
                                            <a href="/brv2/wp-content/files_mf/<?php echo $project_photo; ?>" class="image-wrap" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]">
                                                <img class="project_photo_photo" width="260" src="/brv2/wp-content/files_mf/<?php echo $project_photo; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                                            <span class="zoom-icon"></span>
                                            </a>
                                        </figure>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    <!--END .slider -->
                                </div>           
                        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Absolute perfection! Exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you very much!

Comment: @RedZephyrDesign No problem! Glad it worked! Do you want to know what I did or aren't you planning to go into the whole PHP thing?